# Nagios check_http Trying to monitor multiple servers using sni

Tags: nagios, sni

I have defined the following services:

```
define service{
    use                 remote-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name               linode2
    service_description     HTTP-Cert-website1
    check_command           check_http! -H www.website1.com  -C 30 --sni
#   notifications_enabled       0
    }

define service{
    use                 remote-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name               linode2
    service_description     HTTP-Cert-website2
    check_command           check_http! -H www.website2.com  -C 30 --sni
#   notifications_enabled       0
    }
```

when I run the command from a terminal window, everything works fine.  When I run it as displayed above, I get a connection refused error.

I have multiple websites on this server.  All of the sites resolve properly from the nagios server.

Comment: What is your command definition for check_http?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line:

```
check_command           check_http! -H www.website2.com  -C 30 --sni
```

That should be:

```
check_command           check_http!www.website2.com
```

Because the default defined command is:

```
/path/check_http -H $ARG1$
```

To use check_http with the options you are trying to use, define a new command:

```
define command {
    command_name        check_http_myoptions
    command_line        /path/check_http -I $ARG1$ -C $ARG2$ --sni
}
```

Then modify the check command line:

```
check_command           check_http!www.website2.com!30
```